# 5-inch display GPIO to female HDMI socket converter

Tags: gpio, hdmi, display

I hope you are well.
I have a 5-inch display that only has GPIO for connecting to raspberry pi and there is no other port.
how can I make a converter that connects to this display and give me a female HDMI socket?
[image]

[image]

Comment: You can NOT connect HDMI to GPIO - they have totally different electrical characteristics

Comment: For that you would have to use some sort of converter in between. You could get some hints here if If you would have put a link to the display documentation.

Comment: Buy a screen that does have hdmi.